# Trying to connect the kinect sensor with KinectA(program)

Tags: kinect

We have been trying to get the skeleton tracking working from KinectA. We are using a Mac. Our kinect has already been working with the camera connect to the computer. We used the programs Homebrew and terminal. We need to get the kinect to conect with KinectA but the camera is not showing on the program. Is there an alternativee option we can use or does anyone know how to make it work. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this supported on a Mac? Does KinectA use the Kinect SDK? I'm pretty sure Miscrosoft only supports Xbox and PC for Kinect. Is there some reason you can't use Windows? It's possible that as a webcam is the only way Kinect can be used with OSX.

Comment: yes it is supported by the Mac. We only have Kinect SDK setup.exe. We are not sure how to use it with the KinectA. The kinectA is a program to help us use the skeleton tracking. Our purpose it to get the skeleton tracking working.

Comment: So you're using Windows on your Mac? Their site indicated that only Windows is supported. I mean, it's called the Kinect for Windows SDK.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561

Comment: I found you an article for developing with Kinect on a Mac, note it has you run Windows.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2014/07/28/developing-with-kinect-v2-on-a-mac.aspx